# Calling captured lambda in catch block in another lambda yields GCC error

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, mingw

Consider this code:

```
auto lambda=[] () { std::cout << "Error occurred!" << std::endl;    };

auto lambda_2=[=/*,lambda*/] () {

    try {

        //  Do something
        std::cout << (2+2) << std::endl;

    } catch (...) {

        lambda();

        throw;

    }

};
```

My expectation: This code compiles.

Reality (MinGW 4.8.0):

```
main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:27:5: error: '...' handler must be the last handler for its try block [
-fpermissive]
   } catch (...) {
     ^
```

If I uncomment the explicit capture-by-copy of `lambda`, the code compiles, however this emits a warning:

```
main.cpp:20:19: warning: explicit by-copy capture of 'lambda' redundant with by-
copy capture default [enabled by default]
  auto lambda_2=[=,lambda] () {
                   ^
```

Is this a problem with GCC, or is there some facet of lambda capturing I'm not understanding?

**EDIT**: The following compiles:

```
auto lambda=[] () { std::cout << "Error occurred!" << std::endl;    };

auto lambda_2=[&] () {

    try {

        //  Do something
        std::cout << (2+2) << std::endl;

    } catch (...) {

        try {

            lambda();

        } catch (...) { }

        throw;

    }

};
```

Comment: The warning is expected because the capture mode is by value (`=`). Change it to explicitly capture the lambda by reference (`&lambda`) and the warning should go away.

Comment: Did you read the question or am I totally missing your point?

Comment: You're missing my point. I was just letting you know the warning is expected and how to get rid it. If I was able to verify the issue was a bug (Mike beat me to it) I would have posted an answer with a more in depth description of why it's happening.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Changing the semantics to capture by reference rather than by value is rather an odd way to "fix" a warning; and will break horribly if a copy of the lambda needs to outlive the local scope.

Comment: @MikeSeymour It simply an observation and wasn't meant to be a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [compiler bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56388).

Apparently, it's fixed in 4.8.1, which will hopefully be released [very soon](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2013-05/msg00248.html).